# MAML (Powershell Help) XSD

Tags: powershell, xsd, maml

I am generating MAML files for use with Powershell's Get-Help cmdlet. I would like to validate them. Can anybody tell me if there's a schema file somewhere that I can validate against?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This [post](http://endpointsystems.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AFFCF464FE00AB35!235.entry) would seem to indicate you can get the schemas from the SandCastle project. I haven't tried this myself so YMMV.

Comment: https://sandcastlestyles.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Main/Source/SandcastleMAMLGuide/Content/IntelliSense.aml